# How to run SQL UPDATE for 400 record?

Tags: sql

There are 400 faculty that I have to change their username to faculty00x and password00x. So that x is from 1 to 400. So for example first faculty will have "faculty001" as username and "password001" as password, and so on.

So I can use and update command at SQL and change it one by one,

```
UPDATE users 
SET loginname = 'faculty001', password = 'password001' 
WHERE facultyid = '78388' AND databaseid = 'name of database' ;
```

but it will take forever. So is there anyway to do all at once, so that I do not have to it one by one?

By the way this is how I can get the id of all 400 faculty from database.

```
SELECT "oid", "facultyid" 
FROM "public"."users" 
WHERE "databaseid" = 'name of database' 
LIMIT 400;
```

Comment: are you storing `password` as a `varchar`?

Comment: Since DML has not been standardized yet, please specify SQL implementation you are using.

Comment: Are you tying the password to the login name?

Comment: @PM77-1: DML statements **have** been standardized in the SQL standard. But most DBMS extend that standard to some extent. But I do agree: we need to know the DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are just trying to concat `facultyid` column value which is 001,002,...,400 with `loginname` column; probably you can use a `JOIN` and update like

```
update public.users u
join public.users u1 on u.loginname = u1.loginname
and u.facultyid = u1.facultyid
set u.loginname = u.loginname + u.facultyid,
u.password = u.password + u.facultyid;
```

Again, not sure why you are storing password as plain text which is not suggested.

NOTE: Guessing you are using `MySQL`.

Comment: The syntax in the question is not Oracle - there is no `LIMIT` in Oracle. Looks more like Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Ahh!!! absolutely. didn't noticed that `LIMIT` but noticed the use of `""` for escaping and so the saying.

Comment: `"` for quoted identifiers is nothing special to Oracle - this is how it is defined in the SQL standard.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, AFAIK, only Oracle/Postgres uses `"` for escaping like `[` for MSSQL and backtique for MySQL.

Comment: Well the `"` **is** what the SQL standard defines and all(?) DBMS support that (at least DB2, Firebird, SAP Hana, HSQL, H2, Derby, Ingres, Informix, Greenplum, Teradata and probably a lot more do). MySQL and SQL Server chose to ignore that standard by default - but both can (and should IMHO) be configured to also accept standard quoting style.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Hmm, Good to know that you know those many variant of DBMS though.